# how to disable SendEnv variables set in ssh_config from ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh, debian, redhat-enterprise-linux, openssh

I couldn't find that anywhere so I'm wondering am I the only one hitting such issue.

By default ssh on Red Hat and Debian at least has a ssh_config with SendEnv option passing LC* and LANG variables in the remote session. If one is not root to change /etc/ssh/ssh_config, how can he disable that behavior? SendEnv option seems to be accumulating and I can't see any way to reset it.

And to avoid being asked, I need to avoid passing my locale to test machines to avoid side effects on scripts and programs that rely on locale being the default for the machine.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but can you solve your problem by invoking the scripts and programs on your test machines through `env` or with a wrapper script?

Comment: yeah, workarounds are possible but inconvenient

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're [not the only one](https://askubuntu.com/a/144448). As documented in `ssh_config(5)` you can't unset `SendEnv`, because

> Multiple environment variables may be [...] spread across multiple SendEnv directives.

If you have root on the test machines you could change `AcceptEnv` to not accept variables sent by the client, though.

Comment: crap, I see only -F on command line can help but it's too inconvenient to really use. See https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285

Comment: And how can you change `AcceptEnv` to not accept variables send by the client?

Answer (score 7):

This can't be done in `~/.ssh/config` because `SendEnv` cannot be overridden.

Using aliases won't work for scripts that call ssh.

One alternative is to export a function. E.g. in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
function ssh() {
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8" \
    LC_ADDRESS="$LANG" \
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="$LANG" \
    LC_MEASUREMENT="$LANG" \
    LC_MONETARY="$LANG" \
    LC_NAME="$LANG" \
    LC_NUMERIC="$LANG" \
    LC_PAPER="$LANG" \
    LC_TELEPHONE="$LANG" \
    LC_TIME="$LANG" \
    LC_ALL="$LANG" \
    /usr/bin/ssh $@
}
export -f ssh
```

Comment: This is bloody stupid.

Answer (score 3):

According to `man ssh`:

```
 -F configfile
         Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a con-
         figuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide
         configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored.  The
         default for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.
```

So, you can ssh **without complying with `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`** by explicitly specifying the (default) configuration file on the command line (`~/.ssh/config` is OK to be empty):

```
$ touch ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh -F ~/.ssh/config your_user@your_host
```

You can make an alias for it in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ssh="ssh -F ~/.ssh/config"
```

Restart the bash shell, then you can simply ssh like this:

```
$ ssh your_user@your_host
```

Comment: See my comment above. `if one supplies on command line -F, then the system wide config is ignored according to man page` from https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285 ; it is an option but not really the desired feature.

Answer (score 2):

There's option `SetEnv`, one can force `LANG` to some specific value before sending it.

Also man page says that

> It is possible to clear previously set SendEnv variable names by prefixing patterns with `-`.

but I didn't manage to make this work.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285 , probably that will explain why the `-` approach did not work.
Good suggestion though to hardcode remote LANG and other vars in ssh config. Makes things more predictable. Perhaps `SetEnv` is a newer directive because nobody else suggested about it. `SetEnv LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash you may set up an alias ssh='LANG= command ssh' to disable LANG passing to the other servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `su - youruser` when you are logged in over ssh. This will reinitialize the environment for the user.

Actually you initialize a new session with a new environment.

Comment: Question is to have environment sane automatically. And btw su is not always installed. And you have to type in your password with su. Not useful. There are easier workarounds.